# ionic build fails error 65

Tags: angularjs, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Building my ionic app fails since this weekend:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/i386/IonicKeyboard.o App/Plugins/com.ionic.keyboard/IonicKeyboard.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/me/Documents/app/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,app.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,app,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/me/Documents/app/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/me/Documents/app/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

OSX 10.11.3
XCode 7.2.1 (7C1002)
ionic -v
1.7.14
```

Today I reinstalled cordova and ionic, but I still keep getting the error. I had to adjust another issue with macports ([here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist#xcode7.2)), which I fixed by setting the rights right, but still keep getting the above error.

Comment: I was able to fix this by recreating an ionic project and copying my development files over. Not sure why this happened though, but maybe because I updated to some inconsistency

Answer (score 0):

Error 65 seems to have originate from within Cordova plugins. I've been able to "band-aid" this issue by:

```
cordova plugin remove <plugin name>
ionic platform remove <os>
ionic platform add <os>
cordova plugin add <plugin name>
```

I've also tried using `sudo` while running these commands with mixed results.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with following steps

in xCode go-to "Build Phase" >> Under "Compile Sources"  >> 
did you notice any missing or .m files failed to link... in my case it was "IonicKeyboard.m" file

I just added the file to the list "plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/src/ios/IonicKeyboard.m"

2. then Build Project - worked

Answer (score 0):

iOS

- Open `platforms/ios` on XCode
- Find & Replace `io.ionic.starter` in all files for a unique identifier
- Click the project to open settings
- Signing > Select a team
- Go to your device Settings > General > DeviceManagement

  - Trust your account/team
- `ionic cordova run ios --device --livereload`